# Could not get the apid in the client side/js

Tags: android, cordova, urbanairship.com

I m using Urbanairship with Phonegap. The push messaging is working fine in many cases but I m having problem capturing the "APID" in the client side.
The device is registered and APID is generated but when I try to call the registerEvent in the javascript, the push object is empty and the function is not called.

```
push = window.pushNotification; //this returns an object
push.registerEvent('registration', function (error, id) {//this is never fired
```

I m using PhoneGap 2.9

//in the config.xml

```
<plugin name="PushNotificationPlugin" value="com.urbanairship.phonegap.plugins.PushNotificationPlugin" onload="true"/>
```

If I copy the APID from the logcat(eclipse) and use it, the messaging is working. The only problem is I m not able to get the APID in my client side

Please help

Comment: give your java plugin class

Comment: @ArjunTRaj it is PushNotificationPlugin which was downloaded from the phonegap-ua-push library itself

Comment: i thnk that plugin not suite with your cordova version

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Phonegap 3.0, as stated on the [Github page](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push), and if you look at the [Example/index.html](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push/blob/master/Example/index.html) you can see that they get the push object using:

```
var push = window.plugins.pushNotification;
```

Then push.registerEvent('registration', callback) should work.